# Opencart's lifetime admin token

Tags: cron, opencart, token

Situation:

I have opencart 2v, and have controller in admin to import products from CSV. 
I want to add this controller to cronjob (to run once a day).

But all direct links to admin must be with active token to access. 
Is it possible to create token for that job with no expiration date?

url example:

> `domain.com/admin/index.php?route=import/products&token=cd5f88550277ecbe4bce3a823ac68566`

Comment: please see my solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53244925/1164342

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer: just create in index.php checker and if it's valid run your controller.